# ASP.NET File Upload control File.Exists always returns false

Tags: asp.net, file, file-upload, upload

In my application I have to let the user upload a file into the system and I have this code:

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="CSVFileUpload" runat="server" CssClass="TextInput" Width="250" />
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lbnUploadCSVFile" runat="server" CssClass="MainLinkWithSpaces" OnClick="lbnUploadCSVFile_Click">Upload CSV file</asp:LinkButton>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" CssClass="warning" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CSVFileUpload" ErrorMessage="Please Upload a File!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" CssClass="warning" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CSVFileUpload"
                ErrorMessage="Please make sure you upload a csv file!" ValidationExpression=".*\.csv$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <asp:Label ID="lblUploadError" Runat="server" Visible="True" CssClass="warning" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

In code behind I am always checking if the uploaded file exists, but my problem is that File.Exists always returns false although the file exists on disk at the specified location.

```
  protected void lbnUploadCSVFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        lblUploadError.Text = "";
        if (CSVFileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            if (CSVFileUpload.FileName.ToString() != String.Empty)
            {
                // make sure the uploaded file exists     
                if(File.Exists(CSVFileUpload.FileName))
                {
                  // upload file
                }
             }
         }
  }
```

What could be the reason for that? I am absolutely stumbled by this. I also mention that when using localhost my file exists and it uploads it successfully. Many thanks!

Comment: You need to save the file first... the .NET framework won't do that for you.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day! Works ok now! :)

Comment: It checks if the file exists in the server not the client

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. but I used the same code in other pages and it works well but in this page it does not work. There is a little difference.
Here I use my upload control in a HTML table and they are all in an aspx panel.
and I added triggers too just like my previous ones.
As I put upload control out of table (in panel) it works.

```html
<asp:Panel ID="Topic_Pnl" runat="server">
    <table>
    <tr>
           <td colspan="2" height="20"> <asp:FileUpload ID="my_Uld" runat="server" TabIndex="15" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="myChB" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="myChB_CheckedChanged" TabIndex="20" Text="ok" />
</td>
      </tr>
</table>
</panel>
```

when user clicks checkbox the event runs and I check the uploaded file and save it.but always when it comes to check the answer for 
if (my_Uld.HasFile)
is false